# ethereum token address in Remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, erc20

I am following a tutorial for a crowdfunding smart contract that accepts a token from users.

I have developed a simple ERC20 token, then I deploy the crowdfunding smart contract giving the address of the ERC20 token as the token accepted from users.

I would like to use the same smart contract with ethers. In other words, I would like people to fund the smart contract with ethers (using ganache and remix, my 10 users have 100 ethers each). Therefore, I need to deploy the smart contract giving the ethereum token address. What is the ether's address?

I am working with remix and ganache under web3 provider.

Answer (score 0):

The native token of any EVM network (in your case Ether) does not have any address.

In Solidity, you can:

- Accept ETH with the `payable` function modifier
- Validate the amount sent by the user stored in the `msg.value` global property. The variable is read-only, the sender chooses how much they send and your contract can only validate that.
- Send ETH with the native `.transfer()` function of `address payable` (extension of `address`) type. Do not confuse with the ERC20 custom `transfer()` function - these are two separate functions even though they have the same name.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address owner = address(0x123);

    // `payable` modifier allows the function to accept ETH
    function foo() external payable {
        // validate that the received amount is 1e18 wei (1 ETH)
        require(msg.value == 1e18);

        // typecast `address` variable (name `owner`)
        // to `address payable` and effectively redirect the received value
        // with the native `transfer()` function of the `address payable` type
        payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

If you need to work with approvals and other ERC-20 features, many contracts use WETH (Wrapped Ether) token that uses tokenomics supposed to maintain the same WETH price as ETH has, instead of using the regular ETH. Its production address depends on the network where its deployed. For example:

- Ethereum: [0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2)
- Polygon: [0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619)